# add additional weight to tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, pandas

New to ds but I am stuck on the following:

```
data = [['tom', 'carpenter'], ['nick', 'chef'], ['more', 'teacher']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Occupation'])


X_a = df['Name'] 
X_b = df['Occupation']
y = df['score']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_a, X_b, y, random_state=0)


cv = TfidfVectorizer()
ctmTr = cv.fit_transform(X_a * 0.3 + X_b * 0.7)
X_test_dtm = cv.transform(X_test)
```

Is it possible to split my dataset where the exact same indexes are being used as train & test set and more importantly can I decide that X_b would have a much higher weight in the tfidf than X_a?

The idea is to do a predictive analysis to first predict df['score'] with df['name'] to then predict it again but adding the occupation to X. However currently adding it doesn't yield results as the weight of the occupation is simply too low, that's why I want to manually increase the weight of it to e.g. 70%.

I have been trying the following but feel like this isn't really the way to get it done

```
data = [['tom', 'carpenter'], ['nick', 'chef'], ['more', 'teacher']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Occupation'])

df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df.count()

X_a = df['Name'][:2]
X_b = df['Occupation'][:2]


df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)


cv = TfidfVectorizer()
ctmTr1 = cv.fit_transform(X_reviews) * 0.3
ctmTr2 = cv.fit_transform(X_brands) * 0.7
ctmTr= ctmTr1 + ctmTr2
```

Comment: tfidf need know all the vocabulary in advance, so you should let it know all the words, but then remove the words you do not want it to use. As far as weight is concerned you can either increase frequencies of the words, or apply weights to the resulting tfidf. The purpose of this exercise not quite clear. If you want to know how much predictability was added by a specific feature, XAI, e.g. shap, will do that for you (or lime. or simply feature importance of RF)

Comment: hi Sergey, thanks for taking the time to answer! the goal would be to, as indicated in the post, to do an online product review rating prediction based on 1) the review and  a second time 2) the review + the brand name. I then want to see whether my model improved by adding the brand name against just solely the review.

Comment: Currently, by just adding the brand name, my model's accuracy doesnt even change 0,000000001 so there are two conclusions to be made: 1) its simply quite irrelevant among the many characters of a review or 2) the brand simply doesn't have enough weight in the calculation since it appears way less than other characters